# Add pop up window within view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I want to show a pop up window in my iPhone app whenever I receive a push notification through `didRecieveRemoteNotification`. Something like the windows shown in the image attached. I tried doing `addSubview` with my view controller, but it occupies the entire screen. How do I create the pop-ups?[image: Pop Window UI]

Comment: there is no screen shot attached

Comment: I did attach the image I got from here: [link] (http://mobile-patterns.com/edu) Please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding a subview with dimensions of the screen `{320x460}`, create a view with smaller dimensions such as `{100,100}` and add rounded corners to them via the `UIView` `layer` properties

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

....
view.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
view.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

**UPDATE**: To achieve the background dim effect, contradicting to what I first suggested. Add your PopUp view to a view with a frame of the full screen dimensions `{320,460}`. You then apply a transparency color to it via the `UIColor` `-colorWithWhite:alpha:` method. Like below:

```
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.5];
```